# Adding a Windows Form at a new C++ project

Tags: c++

Okay so I am just beginning to learn C++ and I would like to do so using Windows Forms. I created a Blank project and tried to add a form. I get this error.

`Error  2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Ryan\Google Drive\C++\Hello C++\Debug\Hello C++.exe    1   1   Hello C++`

&&

`Error  1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main C:\Users\Ryan\Google Drive\C++\Hello C++\Hello C++\LINK Hello C++`

I have set my Startup to `main` and set `SubSystem` to `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)`

My Project is called Hello C++ and my form is called MyForm.

Any help? 
Cheers

Comment: I don't want to be a "party pooper", but learning C++ through Windows Forms might not be a very good way to do it. It might me fun but... well no pain no gain.

Comment: I'm gonna agree with CandyMan; if you want to learn it right, learn it proper.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) (which are forms for C# or VB.NET) to a C++ project.

This is not gonna work: C++ is an unmanaged language while you're adding a form for a managed language.

Put it simply: Windows Forms are usable if you choose "C#" or "Visual Basic .NET" as a VS project.

Comment: I think there's this thing called managed C++ running in Microsoft's CLR.

Comment: So how can i add a GUI to a C++ project?

Comment: @AlexM. the post is just tagged C++

Comment: @Rynoh97 There's a windows application template in the C++ project pane, take a look at it. Otherwise a framework like Qt might do the trick: http://qt-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the "Forms" problem, setting /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS means your program is required to have a winmain entry point, not main. That is probably the reason for the error. (You did not show us the complete error message.)

To use Forms change languages to C#. To build a GUI in C++ you can use a Win32 app, or MFC, or ATL, or Qt.

Comment: -1 "setting /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS means your program is required to have a winmain entry point, not main" is incorrect. Microsoft's linker impractically *defaults* to `wWinMain` or `WinMain` with the GUI subsystem, which the C++ standard does not permit for a hosted implementation. In contrast, the GNU tools do accept standard `main` by default.

Comment: +1 @Cheersandhth.-Alf  /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS mean that the linker expects the WinMain entry point and will not link if one is not provided. (one will notice a VERY different argument list)

Comment: @CandyMan: No, it means that the Microsoft linker *defaults* to expecting `wWinmain` or `WinMain`, not as entry points but as the routines called by the expected entry points. It does link nicely when you tell it to do the right thing. The problem is that it must told, that it defaults to **non-standard** behavior. By the way the upvote is silly. The first paragraph is wrong and the second paragraph lists some languages without including the one most close to the language the OP has decided on using (namely Microsoft's special .NET adaption of C++).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  Well I guess you do have a point. Although advising anyone CLI C++ is usually not a good advice since it's a horrible crime (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Well the entry point should be

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  _In_  int nCmdShow
);
```

and not the usual "main". There is good reason for that and you can read about it here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Well WinMain is an entry point. I have never heard any other name for that function except 'entry point' And if Microsoft people say it's an entry point than well... It's an entry point.

Comment: the entry point is the routine you specify to the linker as entry point, with Microsoft's linker via the `/entry` option. consider a Pascal program. it has no `WinMain`: the downhill movement of the MSDN article starts already there, in the very first sentence, by pretending that `WinMain` has anything to do with Windows, when it's purely a Microsoft C and C++ thing.

Comment: Well pascal also required the whole program to be written in a single file (take TeX as an example) so that is a bad argument. Well I'll back my argument with the one and only Charles Petzold who says in his book ' Just a an entry point to a C program is the function main, the entry point to a Windows program is WinMain, ...' (Programming Windows 5th ed. )

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx documents the `/entry` option. the entry point routine for an application is undocumented, AFAIK, but can be found simply by checking the Microsoft runtime library sources (the entry point for a DLL is however well-documented). charles is a good authority in general but when authority clashes with reality, guess what's right.

Comment: Well that is true. I see you're a Visual C++ MVP so I fully admit you are more knowledgeable on the subject.  I just wanted to point out that for us mortals, the WinMain is usually the entry point when it comes to Win32 applications. As you have pointed out the linker allows you to change that, although someone that has just started leaning C++ (like the one asking this question) will probably not instruct the linker to do so :)

Comment: it's no big deal to override the Microsoft linker's default. `/entry:mainCRTStartup` causes standard `main` to be called. with the more standad-compliant GNU toolchain such workaround is not even necessary, it just uses standard `main` if you provide one. ;-)